# Query Entity Framework 4

Tags: entity-framework-4

Is it possible to run a query on an EF4.0 data context and get all objects of a certain type?

Say the context has books, genres & authors but I only have a generic parameter, t. Is it possible to get all of type just by using this t?

I don't think it is :(

Answer (score 0):

```
 var x = from z in context.CreateObjectSet<Person>()
                    select z;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do the trick.

```
ObjectSet<T> set = (ObjectSet<T>)context.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
                p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ObjectSet<T>)).GetValue(this, null);
```